# Returning partial views with the fetch() API

Tags: xmlhttprequest, partial-views, fetch-api, ajax-request

The [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is here as the modern replacement for the old `XMLHttpRequest` API.

Many JavaScript libraries such as [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), [MooTools](https://github.com/mootools/mootools-core/blob/master/Source/Request/Request.js#L42), [Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/) and [Zepto](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto/blob/master/src/ajax.js#L244), etc add the non-standard `X-Requested-With` request header which has become a *de facto* standard and supported by many JavaScript libraries as well as web application frameworks such as [Ruby on Rails](http://devdocs.io/rails~5.1/actiondispatch/request#method-i-xml_http_request-3F), [Laravel](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_ajax), Sinatra, [Spring](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-mvc-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/mvc/extensions/ajax/AjaxUtils.java), Symfony, [ASP.NET MVC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajaxrequestextensions.isajaxrequest(v=vs.118).aspx), etc.

As JavaScript have modernized jQuery have been losing prominence, and AngularJS used to send the `XMLHttpRequest` header but no longer does so. ASP.NET Core MVC no longer contains the `IsAjaxRequest` extension method.

Many web application frameworks have the concept of "partial views" so it can return a view without the header and the footer.

How do I return a partial view in response to a `fetch()` request?

I could add the `X-Requested-With` header to the fetch request but there seems to be [some people](https://github.com/mnot/hinclude/issues/16) who argue against that claiming that is a non-standard header and that it breaks caching in some web proxies, that it can cause an additional pre-flight OPTIONS request, etc.

These people say that the `Accept` header should be used instead. But how would I do that? I want to return HTML content for both types of request, just that the fetch() request should get a subset of the page (the content but without the header and the footer).

What would the value for the `Accept` header be?

```
if page_is_requested_by_fetch_api:
    return content
else:
    return header + content + footer
```

To me it seems that the `Accept` header cannot be used. I don't see how it can be used. When requesting the page normally and when requesting a partial view I would want HTML content, i.e. `text/html`.

- Am I supposed to use the `Accept` header and invent my own non-standard MIME type such as `text/partial+html` ?
- Am I supposed to add the `X-Requested-With` to the headers for my fetch() request?
- Am I supposed to append a query string such as `/page?type=partialview`?
- Am I supposed to have different HTTP endpoints, such as `/Account/Login` and `/Account/LoginPartial` ?
- Am I supposed to fetch the full page, parse the DOM and extract the contents of the `<main>` element?

Comment: As far as the question *“Am I supposed to fetch the full page, parse the DOM and extract the contents of the <main> element?”*, I’m not sure anybody else can say that’s what you absolutely should do—but at least that will *always* work, right? I mean it will always work without you needing to make any changes on the side of the server you’re sending the request to.

Comment: As far as the other bulleted items in the question, the rest of those depend on what the backend is that’s running on the server you’re sending the request to, right? If that server backend has some special support built into it for sending a partial view, then you can just use whatever API or network protocol that server exposes for letting you get a partial view. Or are you asking what mechanism you should implement in such a server backend to provide for partial views? I mean, what mechanism to implement if the existing server backend doesn’t already expose something for that?

Comment: @sideshowbarker I am coding both the front-end and the back-end. So I wonder what is the right way to handle partial views with the fetch API. I control both the client and server implementations.

Comment: OK, I guess what it amounts to then is, the Fetch API itself has nothing special built in for that. It’s functionally the same as XHR, basically. The Fetch API does give you direct control over some aspects of requests XHR doesn’t let you control—but only for lower-level aspects. What it comes down to is: the Fetch API is a relatively low-level API that just provides a relatively thin abstraction over the low-level internal fetching behavior of the underlying browser engine. If you want more than that, you need to instead use some JavaScript Ajax library that provides higher-level abstractions

Answer (score 1):

Your question: *How do I return a partial view in response to a fetch() request?*

I'm using it myself with Razor Pages. Here is the javascript code

```js
fetch(url)
        .then((response) => { return response.text(); })
        .then((result) => {
                $('#container').html(result);
        });
```

And this is the code in the cshtml.cs file. I suppose it will be the same for controllers in MVC:

```cs
public async Task<PartialViewResult> OnGetSomeObjectList()
{
    return new PartialViewResult()
    {
        ViewName = "NAME_OF_PARTIAL_VIEW",
        ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary<IEnumerable<object>>(ViewData, new List<object>()
        {
            new object(),
            new object()
        })
    };
}
```

Comment: But then your web application only works with partial views, and if you were to navigate to that endpoint by opening a new tab, or wanting to bookmark it or share the link, then it would render the partial view instead of the full page.